# Indistinguishable Continuous Version of Martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Assume a filtered probability space, where the filtration is the augmented filtration generated by a Brownian motion.

More precisely, define the set
$$
\mathcal{N} = \{ A \subset \Omega \mid \exists B \in \mathcal{F} : P(B) = 0, A \subset B \}
$$
Then define
$$
\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma( \mathcal{N}, W_s , 0 \leq s \leq t ), \quad t \in [0,T]. $$

Let $M = (M_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$ be a square integrable martingale. Then, we can choose a cadlag modification $\tilde{M}$ of $M.$ By the martingale representation theorem $\tilde{M}$ is continuous up to indistinguishability.

Does it follow that $M$ is continuous up to indistinguishability?

Comment: No, but $M$ has a continuous modification.

Comment: "Assume a filtered probability space, where the filtration is the augmented filtration generated by a Brownian motion." hum ... augmented in which way ?

Comment: Thank you. Now, I defined the filtration.

Comment: Well it also should be right continuous but for brownian motion it is enough that nulls sets are included (but technically not trivial to show that look at Protter's book for a proof of this fact first chapter). Regards